# Getting trends from raw data

Tags: data-mining, trend

Let we have many data which looks like

```
chain of digits  time
23 67 34 23 54 | 12:34
23 54          | 12:42
78 96 23       | 12:46
56 93 23 54    | 12:48
```

I need to found numbers chain trends (grow, fall, stable) . In my example it might be 23 54 or 23. 
Also i want to found different corelations between trends. Data is very big. It might be billions rows. Can you suggest any books articles or algorithms? Note i need information only about trends and corelations in such data type. I donnt need basic data mining books.

Comment: I think solving this problem *in general* (i.e., no restriction on the size of sequences, the number of rows, the memory available, or the time required to perform the analysis) may not be useful.  The problem may not have a *general* solution that is efficient (I'm not sure).  This might be a case where it would be useful for you to provide the broader context of what you're trying to accomplish, so that the most relevant subset of the problem *could* be solved, sacrificing the ideal solution but making something satisfactory anyways.

Comment: Sequential Association Analysis

Answer (score 0):

Here's the grain of an algorithm.  It certainly isn't flushed out or tested, and it may not be complete.  I'm just throwing it out here as a possible starting point.

It seems the most challenging issue is *time* required to run the algorithm over billions of rows, followed perhaps by *memory* limitations.

I also believe the fundamental task involved in solving this problem lies in the single operation of "comparing one set of numbers with another" to locate a shared set.

Therefore, might I suggest the following (rough) approach, in order to tackle *both* time, *and* memory:

```
(1) Consolidate multiple sets into a single, larger set.
```

i.e., take 100 consecutive sets (in your example, `23, 67, 34, 23, 54`, `23, 54`, `78, 96, 23`, and the following 97 sets), and simply merge them together into a **single** set (ignoring duplicates).

```
(2) Give each *consolidated* set from (1) a label (or index),
and then map this set (by its label) to the original sets that compose it.
```

In this way, you will be able to retrieve (look up) the original individual sets `23, 67, 34, 23, 54`, etc.

```
(3) The data is now denormalized - there are a much smaller number of sets, and each set is much larger.
```

Now, the algorithm moves onto a new stage.

```
(4) Develop an algorithm to look for matching sequences between any two of these larger sets.
```

There will be many false positives; however, hopefully the nature of your data is that the false positives will not "ruin" the efficiency that is gained by this approach.

I don't provide an algorithm to perform the matching between 2 individual sets here; I assume that you can come up with one yourself (sort both the sets, etc.).

```
(5) For every possible matching sequence found in (4), iterate through the individual sets that compose
the two larger sets being compared, weeding out false positives.
```

I suspect that the above step could be optimized significantly, but this is the basic idea.

At this point, you will have all of the matching sequences between all original sets that compose the two larger sets being compared.

```
(6) Execute steps (4) and (5) for every pair of large sets constructed in (2).
```

Now, you will have ALL matching sequences - with duplicates.

```
(7) Remove duplicates from the set of matching sequences.
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you Dan! But i think that i found keywords for solving my problem. It's sequential pattern and time-serial sequential pattern. So it's typical data mining task and i can use algorithms from these fields such as AprioriSome, DynamicSome etc

Comment: No data mining task is a typical data mining task.  Hope it goes well!

Comment: I see the word "sequential patterns". If you are interested by sequential pattern mining, you may check my sequential pattern mining project: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/ It will not help you do discover trends. But it can help you to discover subsequences common to several sequences. The project offers 46 algorithms in Java with user interface.  Good luck in your project!